# DynamoDB API Node, is it possible to get results synchroniously?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

I know the normal way to do things is

```
db.query(params, callback);
```

But how and can I do something like

```
var data = db.query(params);
```

If the rest of my lambda can't execute before I get the results, can it just wait for it without having all the callbacks?

Comment: No, programming with Node.js means having to learn how to deal with asynchronous code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no synchronous way for Query api. However, you can use `Promise` for Query API.

> Promises provide an alternative to the use of a callback function to
>   manage asynchronous flow. They allow treating asynchronous calls as a
>   variable, simplifying error handling and providing greater control
>   over handling results from asynchronous calls.

[AWS SDK support for promise](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/support-for-promises-in-the-sdk/)

**Sample code using Query API :-**

```
var table = "Movies";

var year_val = 1992;
var title = "Movie with list attribute";

var params = {
    TableName: table,
    KeyConditionExpression: 'yearkey = :hkey and title = :rkey',
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ':hkey': year_val,
        ':rkey': title        
    }
};

var queryObjectPromise = docClient.query(params).promise();

queryObjectPromise.then(function (data) {
    console.log("Query Item succeeded: ", JSON.stringify(data,
        null, 2));
}).catch(function (err) {
    console.log("Unable to read item. Error JSON: ", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));

});
```

Comment: From my POV, it's kind of the same, with less indentation. But I'll accept this.

Comment: In node v7.6 you can use async-await and await on a promisified version of the query method you've specified (adding no indentation at all)

Comment: Thanks! Good suggestion. However, Node v6.10.2 LTS is the recommended version for most users.